# concat regexp_extract with fixed string on pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to create date (yyyy-01-01) from spark dataframe, if the `year` column contains 4 digit number.

This is the sample code.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("1997",), ("early 2000",)], ["year"])
df2 = df.withColumn(\
    "date",\
    when(regexp_extract(col("year"), r"^\d{4}", 0) != "", regexp_extract(col("year"), r"^\d{4}", 0) + "-01-01" )\
    .otherwise(None)\
)

df2.show(2)
```

However, both rows returns `null` on `date` column. Expected is the first row returns `1997-01-01`. How to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: try using `concat` instead of `+` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that went wrong in your code:

1. The `+` operator will return `null` whenever one side of the operator is `null`
2. This regex `^\d{4}` means match four digits at the **beginning** of the line, while what you want is **any** four digits, so it should be `\d{4}` instead.

So the final code should look like this

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1997",), ("early 2000",)], ["year"])
df2 = (df
    .withColumn("date", F
        .when(F.regexp_extract(F.col("year"), r"\d{4}", 0) != "", F.concat(F.regexp_extract(F.col("year"), r"\d{4}", 0), F.lit("-01-01")))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
)

df2.show(2)
# Ouput
# +----------+----------+
# |      year|      date|
# +----------+----------+
# |      1997|1997-01-01|
# |early 2000|2000-01-01|
# +----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The ^ character only matches the beginning of the line, and removes it. Use concat function instead of + connection string.

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "date",
    when(regexp_extract(col("year"), r"\d{4}", 0) != "", concat(regexp_extract(col("year"), r"\d{4}", 0), lit("-01-01")))
        .otherwise(None)
    )
```